# Draw rectangle (shape) inside rectangle (other shape) with clipping?

Tags: software-recommendation, shapes

Which software allows to draw one shapes inside another ones with clipping? I need this to be done automatically, I know I can draw this in Illustrator with `Pathfinder`. Is there automatic ability somewhere?

[image]

**NOT A CLIPPING MASK**

Many graphic editors have clipping mask feature. But it doesn't match me since mask does not hold the content. I.e. if you move the mask, the "content" will stay in place. In need the content follow the container like window content following the one.

Comment: If you follow my example below, the content will move with the mask.

Comment: @Brendan, cool! And how to move objects inside clipping mask and how to add new objects to it?

Comment: Ah, I can "enter" the clipping group, cool!

Comment: Double-click the hexagon to go into isolation mode (at least that is what happens when I do it; I'm using version 5.5), then you'll be able to move the objects inside. You can also draw new shapes while you are in there. If that doesn't work, select your group and go to the menu button on the Layers palette (top right corner) and then press Enter Isolation Mode.

Comment: Yup, you got it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you're looking to use `Clipping Masks`. Here's how:

Draw your shapes.

[image]

Bring the shape that you want to be the mask to the front (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> or Object > Arrange > Bring to Front).

[image]

Select all shapes and then create the clipping mask (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd> or Object > Clipping Mask > Make).

[image]

If you want the mask to have a line, select it with the Direct Selection tool (<kbd>A</kbd> or the white arrow in the Tools palette) and then change the stroke color.

[image]